# Storing several string with struct in C

Tags: c, string, loops, struct

with following code I can store one string only.

Main problem is how to store several. If i want to enter another string after the first one it wont do it.

I didnt write it in code but when I type("KRAJ") it should get out of while loop.

```
typedef struct{

    char Objekat[20+1];
    char Mjesto[20+1];
    char velicina [20];
    int cijena;
    char kn[3];
    char stanje[20];

}Apartmani;

int main()
{
  Apartmani *apartmani=(Apartmani*)malloc(sizeof(Apartmani)*50);



    while(scanf("%[^,\n],%[^,],%[^,],%d%[^,],%[^\n]", &apartmani[i].Objekat,&apartmani[i].Mjesto,&apartmani[i].velicina,
                &apartmani[i].cijena,&apartmani[i].kn, &apartmani[i].stanje  )==6)
    {

        i++;


    }
    for(p=0;p<i;p++)
    {
        printf("%s %s %s %d %s %s",apartmani[p].Objekat,apartmani[p].Mjesto,apartmani[p].velicina,apartmani[p].cijena,
               apartmani[p].kn, apartmani[p].stanje);

    }
}
```

For example: 
string 1:  Apartman, Novalja, 100.00 m2, 750000kn, dobro ocuvano.

string 2:  Kuca, Ivanbregovia, 20m2, Imtoski, 21252RH, vrijednost-neprocjenjiva.

Comment: Start with defining `int i= 0;` Then `while(scanf(...)==6 && i<50) {..`

Comment: And for strings, don;t add the `&` in scanf, so `&apartmani[i].Mjesto` should be `apartmani[i].Mjesto`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to store several 'Apartmani' structures.
In this case, you have 2 main possibilites :

1. Using array of structures (Fastest to write but less efficient)
2. Use linked-list (More efficient but more complex to use)

Examples

1: Using array of structures

```
#define MAX_APARTMANI 50

int main(void) {
    int i = 0;
    /* Create Apartmani array */
    Apartmani *apartmani_tab[MAX_APARTMANI];

    do {
        /* loop by using malloc on a single element */
        apartmani_tab[i] = (Apartmani *) malloc(sizeof(Apartmani));
        /* While check using scanf */
    } while (scanf("%[^,\n],%[^,],%[^,],%d%[^,],%[^\n]", apartmani_tab[i]->Objekat, apartmani_tab[i]->Mjesto, apartmani_tab[i]->velicina,
            apartmani_tab[i]->cijena, apartmani_tab[i]->kn, apartmani_tab[i]->stanje) == 6 && ++i < MAX_APARTMANI)

    /* good pratice: don't forget to free memory ! */
    while (--i > 0) {
        free(apartmani_tab[i]);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

2: Using linked-list

```
typedef struct Apartmani {
    char Objekat[20+1];
    char Mjesto[20+1];
    char velicina [20];
    int cijena;
    char kn[3];
    char stanje[20];
    struct Apartmani *next;/* add pointer to next item in the list */
} Apartmani_t;

Apartmani_t *new_item(void) {
    Apartmani_t *new_element = NULL;

    new_element = (Apartmani_t *) malloc(sizeof(Apartmani));
    if (!new_element)
        return (NULL);
    memset(new_element, 0, sizeof(*new_element));
    new_element->next = NULL;
    return (new_element);
}

int main(void) {
    /* Initialize Apartmani list*/
    Apartmani *apartmani_list = NULL, *current = NULL;

    do {
        if (!apartmani_list) { /* if empty list */
            apartmani_list = new_item(); /* add first item */
            if (!apartmani_list) /* prevent malloc errors */
                break;
            current = apartmani_list; /* link current pointer to list */
        } else {
            current->next = new_item();
            if (!current->next) /* if malloc fails */
                break;
            current = current->next; /* update current pointer */
        }
    } while (scanf("%[^,\n],%[^,],%[^,],%d%[^,],%[^\n]", current->Objekat, current->Mjesto, current->velicina, current->cijena, current->kn, current->stanje) == 6) /* While check using scanf */

    /* good pratice: don't forget to free memory ! */
    while (apartmani_list) {
        current = apartmani_list->next;
        free(apartmani_list);
        apartmani_list = current;
    }
}
```

NB: I have not tried this code but the final version is probably very close to that.

Comment: your code has many errors. One of them is `apartmani_tab[i].Objekat`. `apartmani_tab[i]` is a pointer, so it should be `apartmani_tab[i]->Objekat`. Try to compiler your code then see the warning.

Comment: Thank you I corrected this, as I said before, I have not tested this code, so it is possible that some errors creep in there.

Comment: you know maybe there are some errors. So, why did you propose the answer to OP ?

Comment: Neither of these code helped, because i want to enter several strings at same time copy/paste. I dont know how many inputs i will have, that's why i have to enter "KRAJ" to end it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use `fgets()` plus `sscanf()`.
2. You should not cast `malloc[Do I cast the result of malloc?][1]`. Remember to check the return value of `malloc`, since it can be failed.

change the line of allocating `apartmani` to:

```
Apartmani *apartmani= malloc(sizeof(Apartmani)*50);
if(!apartmani) {return -1;}
```

3. Do not use `&` for the input of string.
4. Check the value of `i` because its value is limited to `50`.
5. Your code is missing the declaration of `i` (should be: `int i = 0`), and the declaration of `p` also.

Your while loop can be as below:

```
    int i = 0;
    char line[100];
    while(i < 50 && fgets(line,sizeof(line),stdin))
    {
        line[strcspn (line, "\n" )] = '\0'; // trip the enter character at the end of line.

        int err = sscanf(line,"%20[^,],%20[^,],%19[^,],%d,%2[^,],%19[^\n]", apartmani[i].Objekat,apartmani[i].Mjesto,apartmani[i].velicina,&apartmani[i].cijena,
               apartmani[i].kn, apartmani[i].stanje);
        if(err != 6)
            break;
        i++;

    }
```